# 'defer' block within NSURLSession callback not executing

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlsession

Attempting to use `defer` statement within callback for NSURLSession.A precondition is checked via `guard` and returns.

From the literature describing `defer` in Swift 2 , `defer` blocks should run no matter how the scope is exited. (either by return, or break statements.)

However when returning within a closure, the `defer` block is not run whatsoever.

This sample code exits current scope with a 'return' statement as part of a guard check. Running this code in a playground shows the defer block is not called. Removing the 'return' statement causes the defer block to run.

Is this a bug or is my understand of 'defer' in Swift faulty ?

```
let sessionConfig = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
let session = NSURLSession(configuration: sessionConfig)
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://google.com")!)


let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) { (data, response, error) -> Void in
    print("Im done!")
    if let err = error {
        print(err.localizedDescription)
        return
    }

    let goingToFail:String? = .None
    guard let something = goingToFail else { return }
    print ("I'm in here now")

    defer {
        // NOT CALLED
        print("deferring!")
    }
}

task.resume()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to define the `defer` before the `return`s you want it to affect:

```
defer {
    // now it will be called
    print("deferring!")
}

print("Im done!")
if let err = error {
    print(err.localizedDescription)
    return
}

let goingToFail:String? = .None
guard let something = goingToFail else { return }
print ("I'm in here now")
```

Alternatively you can put the defer after the first if with a return in it which cause the guard to execute the defer content as well as the regular finish of the block.

```
print("Im done!")
if let err = error {
    print(err.localizedDescription)
    return
}

defer {
    // will only be called if the guard returns or the closure finishes "regular"
    // will not be called by the previous return
    print("deferring!")
}

let goingToFail:String? = .None
guard let something = goingToFail else { return }
print ("I'm in here now")
```

Simplified explained: Your code just gets executed statement after statement. When the program hits the first `return` it does not yet know anything of the maybe following `defer`. It simply returns.

**A `defer` only affects all scope exits after itself.**